# Convert to british date format issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to convert a date passed to a stored procedure through a parameter.

I am unable to get this date in to British format, here's what I've tried and the results:

```
select 
        N'2015-01-17 11:49:54.253',
        left(N'2015-01-17 11:49:54.253',10),
        cast(left(N'2015-01-17 11:49:54.253',10) as datetime),
        convert(datetime,convert(datetime, cast(left(N'2015-01-17 11:49:54.253',10) as datetime)),103),
        convert(datetime,convert(datetime, cast(left(N'2015-01-17 11:49:54.253',10) as datetime)),113),
```

RESULTS:

```
2015-01-17          11:49:54.253             2015-01-17         2015-01-17 00:00:00.000 2015-01-17 00:00:00.000               2015-01-17 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: What do you mean by British format?

Comment: The date/time format they use in Albania..... :/

British date format, like 13/01/2012

Comment: Nicely sarcastic. Speaking as a Brit we use a variety of formats. Dots, dashes, slashes, ordinal modifiers, so really it depended on what 'you' thought 'British' format meant and therefore what result you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a british format with datetime, so guessing you want this format:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm
```

Convert syntax (can be used on sqlserver 2012+):

```
SELECT FORMAT(cast('2015-01-17 11:49:54.253' as datetime),'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff')
```

Result:

```
17/01/2015 11:49:54.253
```

Comment: This produces the wrong result. Lower case m's are used for minutes, needs to be SELECT FORMAT(cast('2015-01-17 11:49:54.253' as datetime),'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm')

I've made an edit and accepted

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid yes it did produce the wrong result, I appologize.. Please read to edited version.

Comment: That's brilliant, put my on the right tracks anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting to a `datetime`, you wanna be converting to a `varchar` (or `char` etc.) to do any formatting:

```
select convert(varchar(255), cast(left(N'2015-01-17 11:49:54.253',10) as datetime), 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it into a varchar as datetime will always be stored / displayed in format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm'

So use:

```
Select Convert(varchar, Cast('2015-01-17 11:49:54.253' as datetime), 103) as GBDate
```

You can check the MS website for further help with this too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx